# Bash: How to Remove Multiple Prefix Variants From a String

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to remove a prefix of a url string that is parsed from a package.json file using bash. The issue I found is that not everyone enters the repository:url consistently in their package files.

**e.g.:**

`git+https://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>.git`

`https://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>.git`

and I have also found:

`http://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>.git`

So my question is, how do I remove either string prefix that might be found in the .json? Below is my unsuccessful attempt.

```
repo_url="`node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).repository.url' "$(cat $pkg_json)"`"

repo=${repo_url#git+}
repo=${repo_url#https://github.com/}
repo=${repo%.git}
echo "${repo}"
```

**UPDATE:**

I discovered adding a wildcard before the prefix will eliminate everything before and including the prefix. But how would I handle the `http`?

e.g.:

```
repo=${repo_url#*https://github.com/}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your assignments to `repo` uses the original `$repo_url` as the source, so the removals from the previous assignment aren't maintained. You should use `$repo` as the source, except for the first one:

```
repo_url="`node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).repository.url' "$(cat $pkg_json)"`"

repo=${repo_url#git+}
repo=${repo#https://github.com/}
repo=${repo%.git}
echo "${repo}"
```

Comment: What turned out to work best is `repo=${repo_url#*://github.com/}
repo=${repo%.git}
echo "${repo}"`

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` alternative:

```
echo $repo_url|awk  '{print $(NF-2)"/"$(NF-1)}' FS='[./]'

repo="`node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).repository.url' "$(cat $pkg_json)" | awk  '{print $(NF-2)"/"$(NF-1)}' FS='[./]'`"
```

Comment: Thnx but I was needing to keep everything native w/o having the script launch a separate process.